# What does PA1 do in this schematic?

Tags: converter, bridge-rectifier, full-bridge

Original document: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/data_brief/group0/95/79/2a/ed/d0/a0/4f/46/DM00263698/files/DM00263698.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00263698.pdf

The screenshot of the schematic:

[image]

I can't wrap my head around the PA1 thing. Clearly it's connected to the MCU to have something under control, but what does it do? What's mostly likely its purpose?

Also, when it comes to the PD4 and PD5, is it safe to assume they decide the power in-take from the grid, as in this scenario:

PD4 enabled 25% of a cycle (of the AC sinewave), followed by PD5 enabled 25% of a cycle, then the power in-take will be 50%, if both are enabled back-to-back at 50% then it's equivalent of keep the entire circuit up and going 100%? Sorry for my bad literary skills but I think I managed to get the rough idea through.

If that's the case, then PD3 clearly is for zero-crossing detection, no?

Comment: Could it be some kind of wired-or to disable something?

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong but it's like current protection.

R22 is a current shunt. You can say that this is a current sensor.
Q11 and Q12 Current protection. And Q12 is necessary for the latch effect. If the current is exceeded, the IGBT will no longer be able to open. Most likely the GPIO of the PA1 works as a logical input and fixes the overcurrent event.

D12 is necessary to prevent the current from flowing through the dumping microcontroller diodes.The microcontroller itself most likely a pull-up to 5V PA1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm still wrapping my head around it and your explanation sure is a great start! if I may, can you please share a bit on what PD3 does? It doesn't appear to do much but it seems that without it the control program of mine doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Q11 and Q12 form an SCR (see [this page](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-7/silicon-controlled-rectifier-scr/) for more information). An SCR will switch on, conducting heavily between anode (Q12's collector) and cathode (Q11's emitter) when its gate (Q11's base) rises above 0.7V or so. It will latch into this state, and stay conducting even if the gate returns to 0V, and the only only way to "reset" it is to cause current into the anode to fall to zero again.

Q11/Q12's function seems to be to sense current through R22, and when the voltage across it reaches 0.7V (at about 14A), the SCR latches on, and switches off IGBT Q3. It's an over-current cut-off, which will stay active until the SCR is reset.

From what I can see, the Q11/Q12 SCR would normally be reset on a falling edge of the IGBT gate drive signal (from push-pull pair Q4 and Q5), but current from a logic-high potential from PA1 is "diode-OR"ed into the SCR's anode. This prevents anode current from falling to zero, keeping current flowing through the SCR, and effectively inhibiting the reset.

The MCU is therefore able to prolong/maintain the cut-off state, once triggered, by bringing PA1 high.

---

It looks like PD4 and PD5 are triggering or resetting SCRs Q1 and Q2, and may be some kind of zero-crossing thing, or power factor correction. It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [UM1908 User Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1908-stevalild004v2-leadingedge-dimmer-stmicroelectronics.pdf):

[image]